# Mold on soil on indoor mint plant?

Tags: indoors

Please advise if the white patches around the edge are mold on soil? I am new to planting mint indoors.

[image][image: self watering kit]

Comment: Can you clarify  what we're looking at  please? It appears  to be a clump of soil with some evidence of root material sitting in a container with water, and is very wet, with some bluish coloured bubbles or  possibly gel like material to the right  - I'm not seeing any foliage or  evidence of an actual  plant or any mint. Is there a mint plant  somewhere, or are you talking about growing  from seed?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yeap, growing from seed. I am wondering if the white spots are mold or just the seeds growing as it has been about 2 weeks. The blue gel material is the pot which they used to hold the rope as it is a self watering kit, I have attached an overall picture. Thanks.

Comment: How does the pot drain, or doesn't  it? Did you sow the seeds into it (just making sure) and what soil did you use?  Did you buy it as a kit with the seeds and pot altogether?

Comment: nope the soil doesn't drain. yes I sow the seeds into it as shown on the instructions. As I plan to re pot it once it grows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your seeds will ever germinate in that pot - the soil is saturated and fungal activity is almost  a given in such circumstances. If you have any seeds left,sow some in an ordinary pot or seed tray with drainage holes, into new,  damp potting (preferably seed starting) soil. Water carefully as necessary, but don't  let the soil  get soaked, allow excess water to drain away. If its still cold where you are, they may need some heat to get them growing, but otherwise, just stand them on the windowsill, but not in direct  sun all day.  Once they start into growth, wait till each seedling has at least one set of true leaves (the first leaves aren't true leaves), then carefully prick them out into individual pots around 5cm in size (bigger than that little pot you've got there). Further info  on growing here, scroll down to sowing https://www.thompson-morgan.com/p/mint/857TM

Comment: Thank you so much. Will follow your advise and try again. 